# Any simple php lib to auth with Google, FB, Twitter

Tags: php, authentication, oauth

Is there something like Hybridauth3, Loginza, or uLogin (but not those as I understand they are not supported by the teams anymore)? Hybridauth is too complex for me for simple auth.

Comment: Yes, there are a ton of packages available e.g. on Packagist: https://packagist.org/?q=social%20login&p=0 there's; https://github.com/SocialConnect/auth or https://github.com/overtrue/socialite but one could argue that HybridAuth is the best pick as it's most thoroughly maintained (and used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you know how to use code libraries (packages) here is one that is rather popular: https://github.com/laravel/socialite

This one deals with just about any OAuth2 services: https://packagist.org/packages/league/oauth2-client

And here we have a list of SSO packages provided via the composer package manager:  https://packagist.org/?q=sso&p=0

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at thephpleague's package. Their pakages are always well maintained.

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

and even specifics for:

Google (https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google) and

Facebook (https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-facebook)

Answer (score 1):

I have used auth libraries from here
[opauth](http://www.opauth.org) and they work quite well.

Libraries from [oauthlogin](http://www.oauthlogin.com/), are also pointed to be reliable but not free